# Dishwasher shows a drain problem - diagnosis

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Bosch SHEM63W55N model and it *intermittently* ends a cycle with E22 error code. The literal reading of the code is:

`An E22 error code indicates that the dishwasher filter is blocked. The filter is the area where food particles get caught and it needs to be cleaned regularly. Remove the filter to make sure it is not clogged.`

But the filter is not clogged.

Symptoms and what I've tried:

1. The error is always at the end of the cycle
2. There is some standing water (about 2-3 inch), but it's in the drain compartment below the filter mesh.
3. I removed the pump cover and checked with fingers for debris and possible blockage. I couldn't feel any, and the pump was rotating freely.
4. I removed the drain hose from the drainage spigot and the water was draining well into a bucket, so it's probably not a blocked drain hose.
5. The dishwasher is 1.5 years old, installed by me, and was working fine until 1 month ago.

What could be the culprit?

Comment: If you pour water into the sink/house side of the drain, does it drain freely?

Comment: Yes, freely. It was also unclogged about a year ago and drains well. And also, the error happens even when the drain hose is draining into a bucket instead of the drainage system

Answer (score 2):

Since it *thinks* the filter is blocked, but you're not finding any blockages, I would think that the sensor that's responsible for telling the computer that nothing is flowing is failing.

A quick DuckDuckGo search for "BOSCH SHEM55W55N parts list" brought me to [this site](https://www.partselect.com/Models/SHEM63W55N/) that has a parts diagram for the pump assembly. Scrolling through the [parts list for the pump](https://www.partselect.com/Models/SHEM63W55N/Sections/Pump/?ModelID=7091987&ModelNum=SHEM63W55N&mfgModelNum=01&ManufactureID=72&Selected=F7F15812BAD176206B1926175FFD096B52E41D44&Position=5&mfg=Bosch&Type=Dishwasher&Mark=5) shows a [sensor](https://www.partselect.com/PS8727345-Bosch-00611323-SENSOR.htm?SourceCode=20&SearchTerm=SHEM63W55N&ModelNum=SHEM63W55N&ModelID=7091987). *Since you've been in there, make sure that's the area you're talking about, if that's not it, they have schematics for the whole machine, so you should be able to find the filter you're looking for and an associated sensor, if I've picked the wrong one.*

At the current price of $30 USD, it's not the cheapest part to replace on a hunch, but it's certainly not the most expensive part, and definitely cheaper than replacing the whole thing.

*No affiliation with or recommendation of the linked site - it was just one of the first options that looked good.*

Comment: That sensor is (according to Bosch part #), a turbidity sensor. I can't determine whether it also performs a water-level sensing function.

Comment: Pure speculation on my part, @Khrrck, but maybe it uses the presence of turbidity to determine that water is flowing, and lack of turbidity to indicate that it's not flowing, thus determining that the filter is clogged.

Comment: It may not use a sensor to detect the blockage at all, maybe it senses the amperage the pump is drawing. Higher than expected amps == restriction the pump needs to work against. Maybe the pump is simply failing, or some wiring connection is lose or otherwise bad, causing high amp draw.

Comment: It's an interesting theory that some sensor is failing, since it seems to be draining. It does look like it's a turbidity sensor [that detects how soiled the water is](https://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/920-480A_E_LR.pdf). Could be related, but honestly seems a bit of a stretch

Comment: I did notice today that when the error didn't happen the drain compartment / sump had less standing water than when it did with the error. It's still about a cup of water, but yeah - maybe it should have drained it.

Comment: There are a couple of other sensors listed in other parts of the machine, including a float sensor, but without a proper service manual there's really no way to tell what each one does exactly. Unfortunately this may end up being a "replace everything just in case" or "call a technician" situation... Ridiculous that this appliance only has a 1-year warranty!

Comment: Agree 100%, @Khrrck. It may be a "throw parts at it or call the repair man" situation. I'd imagine that several parts could be had for less than the cost of a service call. As noted in my answer, "I would _think_ that the sensor that's responsible for telling the computer that nothing is flowing is failing", i.e. no guarantee that this is _the_ answer - I don't have a service manual either.